# Is there a consistent expression for python list reverse selection?

Tags: python

The case is if I want to reverse select a python list to `n` like:

```
n = 3
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
s = l[5:n:-1]  # s is [6, 5]
```

OK, it works, but how can I set `n`'s value to select the whole list?
let's see this example, what I expect the first line is `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

```
[40]: for i in range(-1, 5):
    ...:     print(l[4:i:-1])
    ...:
[]
[5, 4, 3, 2]
[5, 4, 3]
[5, 4]
[5]
[]
```

if the upper bound n set to 0, the result will lost `0`. but if n is `-1`, the result is empty because `-1` means "the last one".

The only way I can do is:

```
if n < 0:
    s = l[5::-1]
else:
    s = l[5:n:-1]
```

a bit confusing.

Comment: It is hard to tell from your examples what exactly you mean by "reverse select a python list to n".

Comment: If by "select the whole list" you mean "reverse the entire list", why not write `your_list[::-1]` (though `sorted(your_list, reverse=True)` is more readable IMO)?

Comment: In your working example, you could reduce it to a single slice, however it does not really improve readability. `l[5:0 if n < 0 else n:-1]` What are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: Try this `print (x[::-1][:abs(n)-1])` You should be able to get what you want. Btw, `l` is not a good variable. I changed it to `x`. Also, `x[5:-1:-1]` will be an empty list = `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

To fully reverse the list by slicing:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(l[::-1])

#[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

If you want to be able to partially or fully reverse the list based on the value of n, you can do it like this:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def custom_reverse(l,n):
    return [l[i] for i in range(len(l)-1,n,-1)]

print(custom_reverse(l,3)) #[6, 5]
print(custom_reverse(l,-1)) #[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: If you interpret the question as "how do I reverse a list?" then surely you should vote to close it as a duplicate. But it does not seem to me that that is what the OP intended to ask.

Comment: @kaya3 I take your point.  I guess we will wait to find out what OP intended.

Comment: I think its clear that the poster has no intention to fully reverse a list, as its clear by there example they already know how to do this. Based on the example it seems the goal is to reverse to length `n` if n is greater than 0, else reverse the entire list. As OP states the example works, however may be confusing.

Comment: @PacketLoss I see your point. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you mean.

```
print(l[n+1::-1])
```